Initial redirection from HTTP to HTTPS is to a different host, preventing HSTS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/observatory/analyze?host=besch.ws
The test notes that the site has a redirection issue: Initial redirection from HTTP to HTTPS is to a different host, preventing HSTS.
In Apache I do:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@example.net
    ServerName www.besch.ws
    ServerAlias besch.ws

    RedirectPermanent / https://www.besch.ws/
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin example@example.net
    ServerName besch.ws

    RedirectPermanent / https://www.besch.ws/
    ...
</VirtualHost>

The virtual host 443 for www.besch.ws is there the site is configured.
I tried to add the following to the two virtual hosts mentioned here.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
</IfModule>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Practical_implementation_guides/TLS#http_redirection suggest to do
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.example.org
  Redirect permanent / https://site.example.org/
</VirtualHost>

This is what I have and the reason why I am asking here. How to I mitigate this? Obviously, I do not see the obvious at the moment. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Implied in the instructions is to either:  use mod_rewrite and a parameterized rewrite rule  or a dedicated VirtualHost block rather than a serverAlias to ensure that you redirect http://besch.ws to https://besch.ws which allows you to set HSTS headers on besch.ws. Or simply don’t bother as permanent redirects are cached by site visitors and eventually all traffic should go directly to the site hosting your content regardless
